# How can i use if with sleep in C++

Tags: c++

I just started to learn to code in C++ and something went wrong.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::this_thread;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::chrono::system_clock;

int main()
{
    int p;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << setw(60) << "TRO CHOI NHO SO" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << "Hay nhap ten nguoi choi: ";
    cin >> p;
    system("cls");
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << setw(60) << "Tro choi bat dau" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << setw(55) << "VONG 1" << endl;
    Sleep(2000);
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int r;
    for (int index = 0; index < 1;index++)
    {
        r = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        cout << setw(58) << "So thu nhat:" << r << endl;
    }
    sleep_for(0s);
    sleep_until(system_clock::now() + 1s);
    cout << "THOI GIAN CON LAI: 3";
    sleep_for(0s);
    sleep_until(system_clock::now() + 1s);
    cout << " 2";
    sleep_for(0s);
    sleep_until(system_clock::now() + 1s);
    cout << " 1";
    system("cls");
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << setw(60) << "Tro choi bat dau" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-');
    cout << setw(120) << "-" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ');
    cout << setw(55) << "VONG 1" << endl;
    float a,b,c;
    cout << setw(58) << "Hay nhap so thu nhat: ";
    cin >> a;
    if (a==r)
    {
        cout << setw(58) << "Dung roi" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << setw(58) << "Chuc ban may man lan sau" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this program is a memory game that displays a random number that disappers after three seconds.
After that, you put in the number, if the number is the same then say "Correct", if not it will say "Good luck next time" and end there.

The problem is when I try to run it. It ignores the `if` code and just ends.  Why is that?

Comment: `sleep_for(0s);` Why are you sleeping for 0 seconds? Why do you use `Sleep()` if you know about `sleep_for();`

Comment: print the values of "a" and "r" before the *if* and see what you get...

Comment: You probably want to use a debugger to step through the code line by line inspecting the variables at each step to see what is happening.

Comment: `float a,b,c;` you seem to only use 1 of these. Also using 1 letter variable or function names is a very bad practice unless it is for a loop index like: `for(int i =0; i < 10;++i) {}`

Comment: For information on how sleep_for() works why don't you try this code: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop that iterates only 1 time? You may as well just get rid of the loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an issue with your input, so it is recommended to check the `std::cin` call.
I tested this solution on my computer and it worked properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif // _WIN32

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); // Refresh randomizer
    int myNumber = std::rand();

    std::cout << "Look here ---->  " << myNumber << std::endl;

#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep(3000); // Milliseconds for Windows
    system("cls");
#else
    sleep(3); // Seconds for UNIX and *nix
    system("clear");
#endif // _WIN32

    std::cout << "What was the number?" << std::endl;
    int inp;
    if (std::cin >> inp && inp == myNumber)
        std::cout << "Correct" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Good luck next time" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ehh, You are welcome. Remember to vote up helpful answers and comments.